# List of purchases in onPurchasesUpdated

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am implementing in-app-billing for the first time so I am a little confused about new purchases.

As [Documentation states](https://developer.android.com/training/play-billing-library/purchase-iab-products.html#purchase):

> When you call launchBillingFlow() the Google Play UI purchase screen
>   displays. If the purchase order is successful, the response data from
>   Google Play is stored in a Purchase object that is passed back to the
>   appropriate listener. Google Play then calls the **onPurchasesUpdated**()
>   method to deliver the result of a purchase order to a listener that
>   implements the PurchasesUpdatedListener interface.

And the signature of [onPurchasesUpdated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/PurchasesUpdatedListener.html) method is like this:

```
void onPurchasesUpdated(@BillingResponse int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases);
```

My question: Does `onPurchasesUpdated()` method deliver a list of **ALL** purchases initiated until now in my app or **only latest** initiated purchase?

If it delivers all purchases how do I find out latest initiated purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated on the docs you provided, the method deliver a list of the latest `Purchase` objects, either initiated on your app or on the Play Store.

> (...) Both purchases initiated by your app and the ones initiated by Play Store will be reported here.

And if you look at the `Purchase` class [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.html), you can see that there's a method called [`getPurchaseTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.html#getPurchaseTime()) which you can use to check when that purchase was made. That's enough info to track which one was the latest purchase.

But you could also use the other methods on that class to keep track of the purchases, such as `getOrderId()`.

But if you want to check all the purchases the user made on your app, and not only the most recent ones, take a look at the [`queryPurchases()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#queryPurchases(java.lang.String)) method, and take a look at the [*Query purchased items*](https://developer.android.com/training/play-billing-library/purchase-iab-products.html#query) section on the training guide.

Comment: Thank you.  What does "purchases initiated by your app and the ones initiated by Play Store" mean? Why they mentioned 2 kind of purchases? Don't all purchases go through Play Store?

Comment: Also, you said onPurchasesUpdated() delivers only most recent purchases. Just how recent are these though?

Comment: I believe it means each purchased item on the latest transaction, but I had to test it to make sure. The docs aren't that clear about this matter. And as purchases initiated by the play store I t hink they mean directly on the Play Store app, not from inside your app.